# How to make Firefox open download folder in foreground?

Tags: unity, firefox, security

I want to have the "open containing folders" in downloads opening the windows in the foreground, not the background. How can I do it, is it difficult?

I guess it is not doing it to prevent malware, but I really don't care, on macOS it has the desired behaviour.

[image: screenshot of the icon in question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour of Unity (witch is a mess) can be changed from the command line, open a terminal and type:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/focus-prevention-level 0
```

To restore the default value:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/focus-prevention-level 1
```